# ''Command' is not recognized as a internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am compiling `spice 3f5` on Windows 10.

```
C:\Users\myname\Documents\spice\spice3f5> msc51

C:\Users\myname\Documents\spice\spice3f5>set CL=/Gt64 /Os /FPi87 /AL /G2 /W2

C:\Users\myname\Documents\spice\spice3f5>cd src

C:\Users\myname\Documents\spice\spice3f5\src>command /c msc51.bat
'command' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What do I need to do to get the cmd to recognize command?

Or does this have to do with the code not compiling correctly?

I have seen other questions and they talk about paths and something about setting and environment. Now I'm no pro I just want to compile `spice 3f5`.

Comment: `command.com` was DOS.

Comment: You probably just want to run `msc51.bat` in a cmd.exe window. However I don't expect this to work without modification. You may want to do this inside of DosBox instead of windows directly. https://www.dosbox.com/

Comment: I still haven't figured this out if anyone is wondering. If anyone had ever compiled spice3f5 on windows please help!

Comment: What happened when you ran `msc51.bat` from the command prompt instead of `command /c msc51.bat` ?

Comment: Did you try building in a DosBox?

Comment: http://www.rayslogic.com/Software/Spice/compile_berkeley_spice_3f5.htm This was the fifth link when I searched Google for "spice3f5" and I'm pretty sure it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Isn't Google amazing!

Comment: Command.com cannot work on a 64 bit operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ComSpec` variable typically contains the current shell on Windows. In order to make the code most reusable, replace `command` with `%ComSpec%`.